# New toolbar is now activated in Stack Exchange network

Tags: discussion

## The new toolbar was recently activated in Stack Exchange network

[image]

---

## What's the new?

**New Toolbar**

[image]

**Old Toolbar**

[image]

---

**New Inbox**

[image]

**Old Inbox**

[image]

---

**New Review**

[image]

**Old Review**

[image]

---

**New Other Stack Exchange Network button**

[image]

**Old Other Stack Exchange Network button**

[image]

For more details check [New top bar is coming to the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300829/new-top-bar-is-coming-to-the-stack-exchange-network?cb=1)

Comment: <a comment about 1053 reputation> ;)

Comment: I was sure someone would ask that question :) I usually leave the reputation points like this, I am following up my reputation from my home page.  In fact, the green notification makes me feel happy and makes me more enthusiastic :), by the way, these reputations have been collected for a long time and from all the communities in which I participated :)

Comment: this looks cool !! Is it in progress ? Why am I not seeing this :P

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Actually I don't know why :).? we need a confirmation from other members, Maybe it's only activated as a demo for moderators!

Comment: Yes, the rollout is starting with just moderators.

Comment: We'll be rolling out to everyone [starting tomorrow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301845/new-top-bar-next-steps-and-response-to-feedback).

Comment: Good news, Thanks @Pops